# Stamp an image in a document signed without breaking the signature with PdfStamper

Tags: java, pdf, digital-signature

My problem is that I need to include an image in a pdf document that has been signed and that it will not break the signature. Anyone know how to do with PdfStamper or some other library?

Thanks

Comment: You may have a chance depending on the kind of signature. Did it allow addition of annotations?

Comment: Is it possible if the signature allows additions of annotations?